# Html/css - Unable to align custom checkboxes one under the other

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm constructing custom checkboxes instead of the default ones. I need to align them one under another, the problem is if I set:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
```

In order to hide the default checkbox, the rest of the checkboxes don't align in one column. If I set `display:block;`, they do align as I need them, but I see the custom checkbox **and** the default. How do I workaround this behavior?

HTML:

```
<div id="checkBoxesContainer">
        <input type='checkbox' value='valuable1' /><label for="thing"></label> Content 5
        <input type='checkbox' value='valuable2' /><label for="thing"></label> Content 4
        <input type='checkbox' value='valuable3' /><label for="thing"></label> Content 3
        <input type='checkbox' value='valuable4' /><label for="thing"></label> Content 2
        <input type='checkbox' value='valuable5' /><label for="thing"></label> Content 1
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:block;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label
{
    background-color: grey;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4214035/)

Second question, what is the usage of `for` in the `label` and `name` in the `input`?

Comment: Did you try setting labels themselves to `block`? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/y4214035/1/)

Comment: Also, the text isn't wrapped in a tag - you're going to have a hard time with CSS there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first, it's good to put the text inside the label. Second if you set your default checkbox `display:none` then it wouldn't be clickable. You can set it as `visibility: hidden` instead.

The purpose of the `for` is to point to which input are we targeting/bound to. So for checkbox if you click the text label even without clicking the default checkbox it will still check it.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:block;
    visibility: hidden;
}

label span
{
    background-color: grey;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    margin-right: 5px
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label span
{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="checkBoxesContainer">
    <input type='checkbox' value='valuable1' id="valuable1"/><label for="valuable1"><span></span> Content 5</label> 
        <input type='checkbox' value='valuable2' id="valuable2"/><label for="valuable2"><span></span> Content 4</label> 
        <input type='checkbox' value='valuable3' id="valuable3"/><label for="valuable3"><span></span> Content 3</label> 
        <input type='checkbox' value='valuable4' id="valuable4"/><label for="valuable4"><span></span> Content 2</label> 
        <input type='checkbox' value='valuable5' id="valuable5"/><label for="valuable5"><span></span> Content 1</label> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question: The `name` attribute sets, well, the name of the value that should be entered in the `input` element. When the user input gets evaluated, typically by some kind of server side technology like PHP, the values are identified by those names. For example, say you have a field for first name and a field for last name

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" />
<input type="text" name="last_name" />
```

If you send a form with those `input` elements (and probably some more) with a POST request to a PHP script, you can access the values the user entered in the `$_POST` array by the names as indexes

```php
<?php
// any kind of user input filtering, error handling and such
// ommitted for brevity and clarity
echo "<p>Your first name is " . $_POST['first_name'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>Your last name is " . $_POST['last_name'] . "</p>";
?>
```

The `for` attribute of the `label` element connects the label to the input field the label element is, well, the label of. The connection is not done by the name of the `input` element, as one could assume, but by its `id`.

```
<label for="male">Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" />
<label for="female">Female</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />
<label for="female">Other</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="other" />
```

`label` with `for` doesn't have a direct effect on how a web browser displays your page. But there are several interesting effects. For example, if you tell a browser to which `input` a `label` belongs and a user clicks on the `label`, the browser should set the cursor to the `input`. `label`s also give the client reading your code more information if your page isn't displayed in a webbrowser, but for example is read in a text-to-speech system for visually impaired users. Another interesting topic is the so called "semantic web". There you write code that can not only *displayed* by machines (like a browser), but that can be to a certain degree *understood* and interpreted by machines. For this, stating in your code "this `label` element is labeling that `input` element" is obviously helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You must wrapp the content on label tag. 
Using for for focuse your checkbox add label for="ident" and input id="ident".

You can also use ::after and before for styles your checkbox. Example

```
input[type=checkbox]:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: grey;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: red;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and take position relative for your base chcecbox.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4214035/2/)